# Grid view.builder ontap functionality not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

**I tried putting `inkwell` and also `gesture detector` widgets but `onTap()` doesn't seem to work in any scenario.**
I am dynamically adding data to gridView using futureBuilder and I am adding on tap functionality using InkWell and also tried GestureDetector but it seems gridView does not accept any taps!

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: getAllFriends(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7)),
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 4,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                      ),
                      itemCount: friendsList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print('object');
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.amber.shade100,
                            child: friendCircle(
                              friendsList[index].friendPoint,
                              friendsList[index].friendPic,
                              friendsList[index].friendName,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 300,
                      child: IgnorePointer(
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      ));
                }
              }),
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @YasinEge dear I have added the code can you please help.